# Stop Excel Datasheet from loading into PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a PowerBi Report in which i used an excel sheet to load historical data.
This historical data will not be updated and is solely used to merge with other data from SQL.
Everytime I update the new merged query my excel sheet will be updated aswell.
Is there a way to disable that? So that i can delete the excel sheet without losing the data in the PowerBI report?
So far i disabled both the load into refresh option of the historical dataset in PowerQuery but this didnt help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a capability of Enable or Disable loading of a dataset into your model in Power Query on the right click menu. Is it what you are looking for ?

[image]